# JS-jQuery: jScrollPane how to target the stopDrag event?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, drag

I am using Kevin Luck's jScrollPane jQuery plugin this way:
[Styling Scrollbar to Look Like Facebook ScrollableArea Using jScrollPane](http://takien.com/980/styling-scrollbar-to-look-like-facebook-scrollablearea-using-jscrollpane.php)

so that I get same effect as FB does. It all works OK, except that when I am dragging the handle and I am moving out of the pane, the scroll bar dissapears.

The problem is in mouseleave event, that should hide the handle when leaving...

```
$('.jspDrag').hide();
$('.jspScrollable').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.jspDrag').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
});
$('.jspScrollable').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.jspDrag').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

so I did this:

```
$('.jspScrollable').mouseleave(function(){
    var $el = $(this).find('.jspDrag');
    if($el.hasClass('jspActive')) return;
    $el.stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

This would prevent hiding the handle while it is still dragging, the problem is, that it wont disappear after I stop dragging...

how can I target the stopDrag event for the handle?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it myself.. I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works

```
$('.jspScrollable').mouseleave(function(){
    var $el = $(this).find('.jspDrag');
    $('html').bind('mouseup.jsp', function(){
        $el.hide();
    });
    if($el.hasClass('jspActive')) return;
    $el.stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
});
```